# Remove timthumb.php from my custom theme

Tags: plugins, timthumb

I have used timthumb.php to handle various type of image format in my custom theme, but this is making my site slow and more the number of images per page more it is taking to re size, crop them

I am planning to remove timthumb.php file from my theme.Since all my work is at starting phase, so it is not a whole rework for me.

What can be the best approach to accomplish this.Is there anything which needs to be taken care while doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Just delete your `timthumb.php` file.

If your site thumbnails use timthumb then the code might look like this

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/xxxxx/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo "original image url" ?>&h=150&w=150&zc=1" />
```

Just replace those instances with code like this

```
   the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'thubnail'));
```

Comment: Does this take account of the image resizing parameters in the original call?  Doesn't look like it does??